# Replace BeautifulSoup with another (standard) HTML parsing module in this Python script

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have made a script with BeautifulSoup which works fine and is very readable, but I want to redistribute it some day, and BeautifulSoup is an external dependency I would like to avoid, specially considering Windows use.

Here is the code, it gets every usermap link from a given google maps user. The ####### marked lines are the ones using BeautifulSoup:

```
# coding: utf-8

import urllib, re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

uid = '200931058040775970557'
start = 0
shown = 1

while True:
    url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/user?uid='+uid+'&ptab=2&start='+str(start)
    source = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs(source)  ####
    maptables = soup.findAll(id=re.compile('^map[0-9]+$'))  #################
    for table in maptables:
        for line in table.findAll('a', 'maptitle'):  ################
            mapid = re.search(uid+'\.([^"]*)', str(line)).group(1)
            mapname = re.search('>(.*)</a>', str(line)).group(1).strip()[:-3]
            print shown, mapid, '\t', mapname
            shown += 1

            urllib.urlretrieve('http://maps.google.com.br/maps/ms?msid=' + uid + '.' + str(mapid) +
                               '&msa=0&output=kml', mapname + '.kml')


    if '<span>Next</span>' in str(source):
        start += 5
    else:
        break
```

As you can see, there are just three lines of code using BSoup, but I am not a programmer and I had a lot of difficulty trying to use other standard HTML and XML parsing tools, probably because I tried the wrong way, I guess.

**EDIT: This question is more about replacing the three lines of code of this script than to find a way to solve generic html parsing problems there might be.**

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: For anyone interested in the code itself (downloading maps from a google maps user), I have a question specifically about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235639

Comment: You won't get a *really* good HTML parser without adding a dependency. BeautifulSoup exists for a reason. Having a dependency on Python code isn't *that* bad, it's not like users will need a C compiler. Plus, `easy_install` is easily available on windows as well.

Comment: Perhaps I have not made myself clear, I am just looking for a way to perform the operations marked in code without using non-standard modules, not a way to replace the module itself for generic parsing actions.

Comment: @heltonbiker, The logic performed by this code requires parsing HTML.

Comment: Note that Google Maps does have APIs for retrieving data which might be easier (or more allowed) than screenscraping the applicable meat-friendly pages. https://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: @Mike Graham: I have tried to use the referred API with no success (documentation is not always clear), and have either posted another question specific to it (read my first comment). I'll study it further, though. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Python does not have useful HTML parsing in the standard library, so the only reasonable way to parse HTML is by using a third party module like [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) or `BeautifulSoup`. This does not mean that you have to have a separate dependency--these modules are free software and if you do not want an external dependency, you're welcome to bundle them with your code, which then won't make them any more a dependency than the code you write yourself.

Comment: This is intended to be a single-file script for some simple personal use. The 'redistribution' I mean is to send it via email to some few friends :o)

Comment: @heltonbiker, Its simplicity and limited scope does not preclude programming it in a way that works. `:)`.

Comment: @Mike Graham, the user has a program that does what he wants : it works. He just needs to replace a few lines in it.

Comment: I'll accept the answer for now, even if my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

to parse HTML code I see have three solutions :

- use simple string search (.find(),...) Fast !
- use regular expressions (aka regex)
- use HTMLParser

Comment: This is not good advice. Using `str.find` is extremely brittle and not semantically aware of HTML and is not useful for most cases. Regular expressions are *fundamentally* unable to parse HTML; this is a well known theoretical and practical problem. The stdlib `HTMLParser` is unfortunately fragile and unusable.

Comment: I am already using regex in my script, and HTMLParser raised "malformed document" error...

Comment: may this help ? it searches for all links in a page.                                                                  import re 
    links_regexp = re.compile('<a href="?(.*?)"?>',re.IGNORECASE) 
    html = open('toto.html','rb').read() 
    print links_regexp.findall(html)

Comment: @Louis: not much, I am looking for some specific links inside the html tree, as seen in the code with the `#####` marks.

Comment: These options are valid ways to do it whilst staying within the stdlib, they might be poor but it's what to op wanted. Down votes seem unfair.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this code (see below) and it shows up a list of links. As I have no beautiful soup installed and don't want to, it is very difficult to me to check the results against what your code gives. 
The "pure" python code without any "soup" is even shorter and more readable.
Anyway, here it is. Tell me what you think ! Friendly, Louis.

```
#coding: utf-8

import urllib, re

uid = '200931058040775970557'
start = 0
shown = 1

while True:
    url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/user?uid='+uid+'&ptab=2&start='+str(start)
    source = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    while True:
        endit = source.find('maptitle')
        mapid = re.search(uid+'\.([^"]*)', str(source)).group(1)
        mapname = re.search('>(.*)</a>', str(source)).group(1).strip()[:-3]
        print shown, mapid, '\t', mapname
        shown += 1
        urllib.urlretrieve('http://maps.google.com.br/maps/ms?msid=' + uid + '.' + str(mapid) + '&msa=0&output=kml', mapname + '.kml')

    if '<span>Next</span>' in str(source):
        start += 5
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, because it goes on looping forever, and prints (perhaps more than once) a lot of source code in every loop... :o(

Comment: Sorry, I really need to see the output you get to go further.

Comment: @heltonbiker : Can you post your output somewhere, or send it on some junk mailbox ?

Comment: I have put the interesting part here: http://pastebin.com/Qh2HWG1c . By the way, I understand what you are doing, and it is not quite parsing, it is more like regex searching and does not capture the structure of HTML at all... :o(

Comment: Indeed, it does not capture the HTML structure, but I tought you were searching for a list of "usermap links" like said in the question ?

Comment: I drop an eye on your link, but it contents only error messages, not the clean output of what you need. Isn't there some problem ? - What should your program give you exactly ?